# I got a basic maths question, just looking to double check the numbers I came up with.

Tags: finance

I'm trying to work out the [costs of using a google cloud service](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/pricing) when processing some data.

The pricing thats more relevant to my case is:

> $5.00 per 1,000 text records
>
> If the text provided in a AutoML Natural Language request contains more than 1,000 characters, it counts as one text record for each 1,000 characters. For example, if you send three requests to AutoML Natural Language that contain 800, 1,500, and 600 characters respectively, you would be charged for four text records: one for the first request (800), two for the second request (1,500), and one for the third request (600).

**1 text record will equal 1000 characters**

So I've got snippets of text where the average length of a snippet will be 110 characters.

And let's say I have 1 million snippets.

If its $5 per 1000 text records, then I do this:

`5 / 1000 = 0.005` (not sure what the mathematical name of what this is called?)

I can then work out the cost of sending 1 million snippets as:

`1 000 000 * 0.005 = $5000`

This looks correct to me, I can confirm by working with a smaller number e.g. 10 000 snippets = 10 000 text records so `10 000 * 0.005 = $50`

---

So now I want to optimise on cost. I can group snippets so rather than sending 110 characters per request. I have code in place to group snippets so that I can send more text per request. Which in most cases won't be exactly 1000 characters, but close. So to keep it simple, let's assume I'm grouping them by 1000 characters.

So what I'll do is simply, divide the total number of characters sent by 1000 and I get this.

`1 000 000 * 110 = 110000000` - **Total number of characters**

`110000000 / 1000 = 110 000` - **group by 1000 characters**

`110 000 * 0.005 = $550`

If my maths is correct, I'll be saving $4450. Can someone please confirm that my maths is correct?

Comment: Thanks for being very graceful throughout while I was rather rude. I guess very fittingly it was "a snippet of my ignorance". Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the setting correctly:

#### Without grouping

$1$ snippet $= 110$ characters $< 1000$ characters 
$\implies 1$ snippet $= 1$ request $= \$\frac5{1000}$

Totally $1$ milion snippets $= 1$ million requests $\times \$\frac5{1000} = \$5000$ ,  five thousand dollars.

#### With grouping

Nine $1$ snippets grouped together $= 990$ characters $< 1000$ characters 
$\implies 9$ snippets $ = 1$ request $= \$\frac5{1000}$

Totally $1$ million snippets $= \dfrac{1000000}9$ request $\times \$\frac5{1000} = \dfrac{5000}9$ dollars $ \approx \$555$ , five hundred fifty-five dollars.

Basically you bring the cost down to one-ninth of the un-grouped case.

Savings $= 5000 - \dfrac{5000}9$ dollars $\approx \$4444$ , four thousand and hundred forty-four dollars.

Comment: Hey @Lee David Chung Lin thanks, for the pricing it would be $5 per 1000 text records. Where a text record = 1000 characters. Sorry, I should have clarified that.

Comment: I've edited my question to include that part

Comment: @kurupt_89 I already took that into account. Please read that yellow block you cited yourself. A snippet of 110 characters is still going to count as 1 request.

Comment: Hey @Lee David Chung Lin, thanks. So in your answer you've got `1  snippet =1 request =$5` but its actually `1000 snippets = $5` as 1 snippet is < 1000 characters and 1000 characters = 1 text record. I think that's where the confusion is - 1000 text records = $5 `not 1000 characters = $5`

Comment: No, you got it wrong. 1000 characters $\neq 1$ text record. Read the yellow example. `one for the first request (800)...` so the 800 characters is one request, then `two for the second request (1,500)` so the 1500 characters is more than 1000 so counts as 2 requests.

Comment: Sorry I should clarrify a bit more. So from their pricing page heres what they say: `A text record is plain text of up to 1,000 Unicode characters (including whitespace and any markup such as HTML or XML tags).`

Comment: and at the top of the yellow section I have `$5.00 per 1,000 text records`

Comment: Well, it's still the same, $1$ snippet of 110 characters is 1 request, it's only scaling down to 1 request being $5/1000$ dollars. Just divide everything by 1000.

Comment: If I'm sending 1 snippet thats less than 1000 chars. A request would actually just be 1 text record. So 1000 requests would be $5

Comment: You really should have add in the beginning that "records means snippets, or tweets, or messages", cuz from the yellow block , it reads as if they use "record" and "request" interchangeably (and I very deliberately viewed the "$5 per 1000 records" as a typo (replace it with "1000 characters"), since in the end it is the request that counts). They also gave bad examples though. They should have included examples with multiple records within one request.

Comment: Anyway, the calculation is updated. Please see if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Yeah I agree their examples are confusing. Thanks a lot @Lee David Chung, and apologies for the confusion :). Your answer looks good to me thanks for taking the time to verify.